# How do you capitalize "spam"?

Tags: capitalization

Is it legitimate to put "spam"  (the junk email kind, not the trademarked meat) in all caps?

An example I've recently read is

> Please read before flagging as SPAM (a reminder from your moderators)
>   – ends Sep 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ordinary formal writing, *spam* should not be capitalized. In your example, the author could have capitalized it for emphasis or because it reflects the way it is written in the user interface.

Comment: Can you cite a source for this rule?

Comment: Seems logical to me. *Spam* looks like a proper noun, so I would assume it is the "meat product". *spam* is unsolicited commercial email (UCE). *SPAM* probably refers to UCE but is actually the correct trademark of the meat product.